# Why do I get the "Type-declaration character does not match declared data type" in my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, integral

I wrote a program which calculates the integral of the probability density function of the lognormal distribution.
I want it to be able to calculate the nth moments of the pdf too. But if I modify my code I get this error. It works properly before I add `*(x^(M))`

```
Function riemanint(n, a, b)


Dim h, i, x
h = (b - a) / n
x = a - h / 2
    For i = 1 To n
    x = x + h
    s = s + f(x, ev, var, PI, M) * h
    Next
riemanint = s
End Function

Function f(x, ev, var, PI, M)


PI = Application.WorksheetFunction.PI()
ev = Range("D2")
var = Range("E2")
M = Range("F2")

f = (((1 / (x * ((2 * PI) ^ 0.5) * var)) * Exp((-(Log(x) - ev) ^ 2) / (2 * var * var)))) * (x^(M))
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't know why doesn't it work for me then.

Comment: Well, it may be I'm providing different inputs from you. If you can post some example parameter values that would help.

Comment: What about D2, E2, F2 ?

Comment: Okay, I don't know why, but it has stopped giving me this error.